# Написание цикла для перебора массивов в модальном окне при парсинге "на лету". PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, парсер, modal

Парсится информация с сайта с модального окна по url например `site.com/regions/Modal/....`
Выгружается в моё модальное окно 10 основных вкладок с регионами.
Выглядит так:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=8)
      'isFolder' => boolean true
      'title' => string 'МосОбласть' (length=63)
      'key' => int 5555
```

На сайте-доноре при нажатии на основную вкладку появляются вложенные вкладки, которые имеют  url вида `site.com/region/children.html?parentId=5555`. `ParentId` берется, как вы поняли из ключа `'key'`  в основном массиве.
Результат нажатия на вложенную вкладку:

```
 array (size=3)
      0 => 
        array (size=8)
          'isFolder' => boolean true
          'title' => string 'Казань' (length=63)
          'key' => int 5894
      1 => 
        array (size=8)
          'isFolder' => boolean true
          'title' => string 'Москва'
          'key' => int 5557
```

Каждое значение `'key'`из вложенной вкладки можно подставить в `/children.html?parentId=` и будет следующий уровень массивов.
И такая вложенность массивов продолжается до тех пор пока не останется один массив и  ключ `'isFolder'` не будет иметь значение `false`, что означает что дальше пути нет.
Вот в связи с этим вопрос как грамотно составить цикл который будет подставлять в `?parentId=` значение `'key'` которое будет приходить и подставляться каждый раз когда пользователь нажал на раскрытие вкладки, до тех пор пока ключ `'isFolder'` не будет `false` и раскрытие вкладки будет неактивным.

Заранее извиняюсь за сумбур, опыта в разработке пока немного.

Comment: если вам нужно составить дерево, то используйте функцию с рекурсией. Она будет проверять флаг `isFolder` и в зависимости от значения спускаться ниже

Comment: Здравствуйте. Спасибо за ответ, можете чуть более подробно подсказать что в теле цикла после проверки isFolder указать?